# If (NULL), will it work?

Tags: javascript

Okay so i am using the following code.

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="html.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getName()
    {

    if(name)
    alert("you thought i forgot you" + name + "?");
    else
    name=prompt("what's your name","here");


    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="var name;">
    <p onclick="getName()"; >click here</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now if on clicking the `<p>` text first time it prompts me, and if I click cancel without entering my name, and then again click the `<p>` text, it doesnt prompt me anything,

instead it shows the name to be filled as NULL. now in `C`,

```
char a=NULL;
if(a)
```

evaluates to false, doesn't it happen in javascript?

Comment: Yeah, null, undefined, false, and 0 are all falsey. Null is lowercase in JS.

Comment: okay, so how do i make it work like this, on the first prompt, if i dont enter any name, and cancel it, and on the second name i want it to ask me again for my name. but instead what is happening is that on the first prompt if i cancel it(i.e. i dont enter anything) it takes it as 'Null' and hence it doesnt return false on if(name).

Comment: Javascript and C are quite different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you might be running into: when you set the global `name`, you are actually setting [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.name). [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.name) is a special property that actually persists even after refreshing the page.

Try making a page with the script:

```
alert(window.name);
name = 'hello';
```

On the first run, it should alert "undefined". If you refresh the page, though, you should see "hello".

You can avoid the problem by renaming `name` to something else.

Comment: This is clearer than my answer. The heart of the matter is, name is reserved and shouldn't be used.

Comment: any more of the identifiers that i shall be using more carefully?

Comment: I think you have it, compare the behavior of http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/xtLsR/ and http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/aCyZX/

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```
if (name==undefined)
name=prompt("what's your name","here");
else
alert("you thought i forgot you" + name + "?");
```

Comment: the result of this is, on the very first click it replies with "you thought i forgot you"   doesnt prompt me at all.

Comment: yeah, i did that too, it aint prompting me for my name, not even once!

Comment: var name; has no value so it replies "you thought i forgot you"

Comment: why? isnt name==undefined the first time i just write var name;??

Answer (score 1):

This fiddle behaves as you desire, I think:  http://jsfiddle.net/YUCyL/5/

As you can see, I moved the variable declaration to the head and renamed it to username instead of "name".

Comment: okay, i see what you are doing, but i dont get that if on the first time when it asks for my name, if i cancel it, why doesnt your username take the value 'Null' as it takes in my case, which causes it to show the name, the second time i click it , as Null?

Comment: @Nathan - huh? why doesnt your username store 'Null' on first time cancellation and print the value the second time??

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky situation.

The identifier "name" is special for the global window object so you cannot use it reliably as a variable.

Using for example `name$` your code works as expected.

Also I think that "onload" requires an expression, not a statement; so you cannot use it that way. Apparently works with `name` because that is predefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="html.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var name;

function getName() {
    console.log(name, typeof name);
    if(name && name !== 'null') {
        alert("you thought i forgot you" + name + "?");
    } else {
        name=prompt("what's your name","here");
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p onclick="getName()"; >click here</p>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see from the console output, name is a string with value null. This is pretty stupid, but I guess window.name stringifies the value, in this case null.

EDIT:

You probably shouldn't be using the word name as it's reserved (used as a property in window).

window.name returns a string value of whatever is stored in it.  For example:

`window.name = null;`

`window.name === 'null'` true

`window.name === null` false

Comment: -still dont get it, if on my first prompt i cancel it then my name='Null' and now if i click again, then what does console.log() expression does that it changes 'Null' to 'null'.?

Comment: console.log just logs to your console. Firefox and chrome both have consoles (useful for debugging). I think name is an ES5 setter and they're stringifying the input (e.g. null -> 'null'). I'm not sure though, but it's definitely better to avoid the keyword name.

Comment: okay i do that, but can you help me with the doubt i posted at Nathan's answer above?

Comment: When using the variable `name`, it is trying to access `window.name`, which is turning the value of null to `null`.  I just added this to my answer.

Comment: i got what you are saying, i was referring to this solution. http://jsfiddle.net/YUCyL/5/
in this it is using username instead of name, so on the first time prompt, if i cancel then according to my question,username shall store 'Null' and hence since 'Null' != null hence on the second click,it will alert me with you thought i forgot you. but instead when i cancel the first prompt, it stores 'null', and not 'Null'. Why?

Comment: It will be storing the actual value, `null`, not the string 'null'. There's a difference. `window` is converting the types for you. `username` is not reserved, so it will not convert types for you, so whatever you put in, that's what you'll get out.